# Install Matplotlib on Apple Silicon

Tags: python, matplotlib, homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Im very new to python and we needed Matplotlib for a class! I wanted to install it using pip but it only gives me errors, and then tries one older version and so on!
I installed the latest version of python (3.9) with homebrew.

So my question is, how do I install Matplotlib onto my M1 mac?

Im planing to use it in VS Code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install matplotlib` ?

Comment: @BPDESILVA  Of course, that was the first thing i tried! But as i said, it just came with a ton of error messages (as mentioned above)

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122146/pip-install-matplotlib-fails-on-m1-mac/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a well described solution here on StackOverflow the other day, which helped me tackle my problem, im posting it here, if anybody is still searching for some advice:

Here is the Post:
[unable to install matplotlib with python3 on m1 mac using pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204654/unable-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-on-m1-mac-using-pip3)

Have a nice day!