# Unable to install Matplotlib with Python 3 on M1 Mac using pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip, apple-m1

I'm unable to install Matplotlib through pip on my M1 Mac. I have Python 3.9.1 installed through Homebrew. I've tried the solution here: [Pip install matplotlib fails on M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122146/pip-install-matplotlib-fails-on-m1-mac) but it does not work for me.

I get this long error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-mrz7uc56/matplotlib_20151701613b4e6fb6955488fa89e81e/setup.py", line 256, in <module>
    setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 299, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 541, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 577, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
    self._add_defaults_ext()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-mrz7uc56/matplotlib_20151701613b4e6fb6955488fa89e81e/setup.py", line 88, in finalize_options
    self.distribution.ext_modules[:] = [
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-mrz7uc56/matplotlib_20151701613b4e6fb6955488fa89e81e/setup.py", line 91, in <listcomp>
    for ext in package.get_extensions()
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-mrz7uc56/matplotlib_20151701613b4e6fb6955488fa89e81e/setupext.py", line 345, in get_extensions
    add_numpy_flags(ext)
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-mrz7uc56/matplotlib_20151701613b4e6fb6955488fa89e81e/setupext.py", line 468, in add_numpy_flags
    import numpy as np
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
```

I am able to import Matplotlib with Python 2.7 on my Rosetta Terminal but I am trying to use Matplotlib with Python 3 instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install matplotlib fails on M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122146/pip-install-matplotlib-fails-on-m1-mac)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### November 2021 Update

Just run the following command:

```sh
$ pip3 install matplotlib
```

Worked on Mac mini (M1, 2020), Monterey 12.0.1. Python 3.9.7

### Feb 2021 Answer Below

In order to install `matplotlib` with pip3 on an M1 mac, you first need to install the dependencies `Cython`, `numpy` and `Pillow` from source. The following method worked for me.

0. Install `Cython`

```sh
pip3 install Cython
```

1. Install `numpy`

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
$ cd numpy
$ pip3 install . --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517
```

2. Install `Pillow`

`libjpeg` is necessary for Pillow so you might want to install it via brew.

```sh
$ brew install libjpeg
$ git clone https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git
$ cd Pillow
$ pip3 install . --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517
```

3. Install `matplotlib`

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
```

Then you need to manually download `qhull` and extract the archive. (http://www.qhull.org/download/qhull-2020-src-8.0.2.tgz on [Qhull Downloads](http://www.qhull.org/download/))
You will get a folder named `qhull-2020.2`. You then have to place the folder at `matplotlib/build`. The `build` folder may not exist so you might have to create it.

Lastly, the following command will install the `matplotlib` on your M1 mac.

```sh
$ cd matplotlib
$ pip3 install . --no-binary :all:
```

Tested for Python 3.9.1 on non-Rosetta terminal on M1 Mac mini (Big Sur 11.2.1).

Comment: I successfully installed matplotlib by following your instructions. Thank you . But I have this error: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
 /Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: it says "Successfully installed matplotlib-3.5.0.dev1355+gb9325758d7"

Comment: When I run 'brew install libjpeg' in non-rosetta terminal, it tells me to use brew under /opt/homebrew. So I just run '/opt/homebrew/bin/brew install libjpeg' and it actually succeeds with version 9 of jpeg library. But then the installation of Pillow still errors out and prompts many error info which looks like related with jpeg. Any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately today it gives a:

ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project specifies a build backend of setuptools.build_meta in pyproject.toml

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by just uninstalling homebrew first and downloaded matplotlib with python3. After that i reinstalled homebrew using non-rosetta terminal. Idk how it works cause im very new to these stuff but what works works i guess.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by realizing that I had two seperate Python instances installed. When you run `which python3` you get the path of your Python installation. Check to see if the path corresponds to the Python version you installed.

I fixed it by uninstalling the version of Python3 I had installed with homebrew with `brew uninstall python3`.

When I did `which python3` again it showed a different Python installation path. I then did `pip3 install Matplotlib` and I was able to import Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Uninstall Following Package**

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall wordcloud
pip uninstall matplotlib 
pip uninstall pyparsing
pip uninstall kiwisolver
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip uninstall cycler
pip uninstall packaging
pip uninstall fonttools
pip uninstall contourpy
pip uninstall six
```

**2. Install matplotlib**

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score -1):

I originally installed python 3.9 using homebrew, but my matplotlib problem was fixed by uninstalling python and reinstalling using the download from the python website(because of architecture problems).

Answer (score -2):

I found another nice way with `pyenv`,`miniforge` and `conda`.

- `pyenv install miniforge3-4.10`
- `conda create -n env_new python=3.9`
- `conda activate env_new`
- `conda install poetry`
- `peotry new project`
- `poetry add matplotlib`

Maybe it is not perfect, but it works for a variety of moduls and you can even choose `python=3.8` and other python versions and everything is running on the M1.